# format axis labels in lattice

Tags: r, format, label, lattice

How can I put my axis labels in a convenient format in lattice?

```
require(stats)

xyplot(lat*1000000 ~ long, data = quakes)
```

gives me y-labels like `-3.5e+0.7`. I would want lattice to write the whole number.

(maybe it is easy, but I can't find a solution.)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of "global options" that might affect how values are printed. In this case `scipen` is the one you want to move:

```
old_op <- options(scipen=10)
xyplot(lat*1000000 ~ long, data = quakes)
options(old_op)
# probably better to restore it so the rest of you session is more "normal"
```

Answer (score 9):

Create your own labels and pass them to the `scales` argument.

```
y_at <- pretty(quakes$lat*1e6)
y_labels <- formatC(y_at, digits = 0, format = "f")
xyplot(
  lat*1000000 ~ long, 
  data = quakes, 
  scales = list(
    y = list(
      at = y_at, 
      labels = y_labels
    )
  )
)
```

For the formatting step, there are lots of alternatives to `formatC`.  Take a look at `format`, `prettyNum` and `sprintf` to get you started.

---

If you want to do this with dates, then note that `scales` accepts a `format` argument for that purpose.

Comment: I was hoping there is an easier way. Thank you!